# Get OneDrive for Business use's quota using windows form application

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am newbie for OneDrive for Business. I wanted to get user's available free space in OneDrive for Business using windows form applications, c#.
e.g. On button click, I want to show how much total quota the current user have and how much free space available.

Comment: I would have a look here: https://dev.onedrive.com/sample-code.htm

Comment: I tried running this code, gave the permission to use my OneDrive account but ended up throwing error "An error occurred while sending the request". Also, It looks like this is for OneDrive not OneDrive for Business.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onedrive api v2.0 for this.

Call for GET --> https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drive and get drive information. In the drive response you will be having **QUOTA** facet.

***[Sample response](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/drive.htm#)*** response has been truncated for readability.

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "driveType": "personal | business",
  "owner": { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.identitySet" },
  "quota": { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.quota" },

  "items": [ { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.item" } ],
  "root": { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.item" },
  "special": [ { "@odata.type": "oneDrive.item" }]
}
```

Here you can get the storage/quota information.